# What does “occasion of sin” mean?

Tags: religion, social-interaction

I am watching Grace and Frankie, S2:E9 in which Robert and John are talking to each other at a park. John asks him the reason for coming out the closet so late, to which Robert replies that he fell in love.

John then goes on to say, “Maybe we’re the lucky ones”.

Robert: How’s that?

John: When you come out young these days, it’s difficult to avoid the *near occasion of sin.*

Robert: Amen.

Comment: Interesting treatment of this at our sister Stackoverflow site: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71236/should-dating-couples-who-put-themselves-regularly-to-the-occasion-of-sin-be-gra . "Occasion of sin" would be familiar to someone who had attended Catholic school.

Comment: As someone who endured 12 years of Catholic school, I understood it to mean one should avoid people or places that may lead to sin: bad friends, bars (those "dens of iniquity"), etc.